# How to manually assign an Image to UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to add an Image to UIImageView programmatically.

I found a code from here that I've tried a few times but it stopped working for some reason.

popupImage.image=UIImage(named: "juice")

I get this error message:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: it looks like the uiimageview you try to assign the image to is nil, could you show us full view or ViewController?

Comment: Here is my storyboard [https://gyazo.com/f50b851b70962ac8389f746643dd7cb1]  .. Here is my ViewController [https://gyazo.com/3789de8be042c00a0a14d02c2ef96e22]

Comment: Going to need to see how you initiate the viewController with the imageView inside it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: If you from another storyboard open that viewController by code you might have not initiated it through the storyboard and it will cause your outlets to be nil. However, since the image is being set on the buttonAction i guess the . outlets are being set.  so its a difficult one

Comment: You could try (at the crash) in the console write `po popupImage` and see what response you get

Comment: So how do I solve the problem and show the image from the button click? Is there any other way to do it correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196060/discussion-between-vollan-and-ya3goobs).